# Grafana Stat Visualization, Handling Counter Resets in Prometheus with Lazy Initialization and Numerous Tags

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, reset

I'm facing a challenge visualizing Prometheus counters in Grafana. The counters sometimes exhibit odd behavior, especially when they reset. I believe the root cause is related to the lazy initialization of these metrics in our system. Due to the number of tags and their potential values, upfront initialization is not practical, making our approach lean towards lazy initialization.

I'm trying to view the metric in Grafana as stat visualization that displays a single number per partner representing the number of signups for each partner over the resolution I have set. So if I am looking at an hour I wanna now the total signups for each partner for that hour as a single number.

Here's is my query:

`sum(increase(app_user_registrations{source="appA",success="true"}[$__range])) by (partnerId)`

app_user_registrations is the counter metric representing user registrations.
The problem arises when our application counters reset due to deployments. Each partner's variation of the metric will be missing until the user create route is hit for each partner.

What this can look like in scrapes for say partner X:

app_user_registrations{source="appA",success="true",partnerId="X"} 520 // at T=0
app_user_registrations{source="appA",success="true",partnerId="X"} 525 // at T=1
app_user_registrations{source="appA",success="true",partnerId="X"} 1   // at T=2
app_user_registrations{source="appA",success="true",partnerId="X"} 15  // at T=3

I'm expecting the stat for partner X to equal 20 but instead it displays 10.1.

I've attempted various solutions, like the rate(), increase(), and changes() functions, to capture and handle these resets, but haven't found a consistent workaround.
I've also tried clamping and `OR on() vector(0)` although I don't know if I applied them correctly.

Considering the lazy initialization and the tag variations, how can I adjust my Prometheus query to account for potential missed counter resets, ensuring I always have a correct and consistent view of the data?

Note: the tags I share here is not the complete set.

Comment: Results you shared in question don't make much sense to me: blocks of absence in counters should not affect function `increase`, at least AFAIK. Can you share a graph (as in timeseries panel or Explore page) of raw metric values and results of increase call?